# how to use excel solver to get the shares weights minimize a risk indicator given a fixed profitability I want to make?

Tags: excel

I don't know whether this question should have better been asked on Quantitative Finance's forum or Cross Validated or Super-User.

I want to minimize a risk indicator given a fixed profitability I want to make from five financial shares. Therefore I applied the solver from Excel to get the weight in percentage I should use from my constraints and objective function.

Yet after a few turns it always gives me a wrong output as far as I get negative weights for these actions even though I specified I only wanted positive weights (I am not considering to borrow money to sold this share without having it).

**Therefore how to use excel solver to get the shares weights minimize a risk indicator given a fixed profitability I want to make?**

[image]

Comment: Simplex is only for linear equations.  Your variable cells should be $C$174:$F$174.  You can leave the constraint for $G$174 assuming it is not possible for your "risk indicator" to have negative value.  Also, I don't think this question belongs in this forum...probably SO is better if you need more help.  Good Luck.